# Errors on newFactory() when using RowSetProvider

Tags: java, jdbc, cachedrowset

Trying to create a CachedRowSet from a ResultSet in Netbeans11.2 (java) but error occurs finding newFactory() in the RowSetProvider class. i.e.

```java
RowSetFactory factory = new RowSetProvider.newFactory();
```

errors on newFactory.

I have imported - `javax.sql.rowset.*`;

Checked JAVA SE 13.0.1 is installed and activated as per hints.
Maybe a configuration problem 
Any clues?

Comment: What is the error? If you are on Java 13, is your project modular (ie does it have `module-info.java`)?

Comment: OK Got it - Thanks